# doInBackground is called after on post execute

Tags: android

There are similar questions like this but it didn't  solved my problem . My on post execute runs before doInBackground, i guess i am not doing any ui work in doInBackground , but still on post execute runs before doInBackground.Below is my code.

```
 sumbit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mail = resMail.getText().toString();
            String id = resUniq.getText().toString();

            new Reset_Pass_Task().execute();

        }
    });
}

private class Reset_Pass_Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", "xyz@gmail.com");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if (e==null){

                        for(ParseUser singleobject:objects){
                            name23 = (String) singleobject.get("uniqueId");

                        }
                    }else {
                        Log.i("abc",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("xys",e.toString());
        }



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        if (name23!=null){
            Log.i("def",name23);
        }else {
            Log.i("ijk","null");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it is quite obvious that query.findInBackground is asynchronous and thus return null is executed before the query is complete

Comment: so any suggestions,i dont think its returning null and giving my results in next attempt

Comment: so i shouldn't use doIn Background?

Comment: **void** methods are **not supposed to return anything**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **doInBackground** you're already in a TaskThread.
If you have access to a sync method for ** findInBackground** call it there. Otherwise, just remove the AsyncTask altogether as the **findInBackground** call is async already.

Here your problem is that, for the doInBackground, the only thing "visible for it" is that you're launching a function that returns automatically. It's not waiting for the async call to be complete.

Suggested fix :

```
private void resetPassword() {
try{
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", "xyz@gmail.com");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if (e==null){

                        for(ParseUser singleobject:objects){
                            name23 = (String) singleobject.get("uniqueId");

                        }
                    }else {
                        Log.i("abc",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("xys",e.toString());
        }
}
```

And just call **resetPasswordAsync()** instead of **new Reset_Pass_Task().execute()**

Comment: I'm not sure, if `done(...)` is executed back on the main Thread, so maybe you should add `runOnUIThread` in `done(...)`

Comment: Good point @JohnnyAW, however the entire done() method doesn't really makes sense so far, overriding a variable and not doing anything else with it. But you're right, if there was something like "get the new text and display it in a TextView", OP should ensure that **done()** runs is back on the UIThread, otherwise call **runOnUIThread()**